# Python and pip incompatible

Tags: python, macports

I've installed python via Macports and have now Python 3.12. (MacOS 11 comes with Python 3.8)

When I run `pip3 --version` I get this:

```
/Users/ingmar/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

And more importendly, packages installed via pip3 are not found when running the script via python3, which now points to Python 3.12 from Macports. (Don't know how to run Python 3.8 from MacOS)

I've also installed `py-pip` from Macports and ran `sudo port select --set pip3 pip312`, but the `pip3 --version` output remains the same.

So, how do I make `pip3` to point to the version installed via Macports so that packages installed can be found by `python3`?

Comment: I recommend installing `pyenv` or some similar version manager and using it to manage python versions, easier than manually installing python versions like you tried

Comment: Why don't you just alias `pip3` to `python3 -m pip` ?

Comment: That would work I guess, but is this really the proper solution? (Regarding the alias suggestion)

Comment: Regarding your first comment, could you expand on that? I thought that pyenv serves to separate depencies for multiple projects. I still would have to install python itself manually, right? I mean, this funny situation is only because MacOS slips me an old python version.

Comment: pyenv also installs python versions for you. Maybe you are thinking of pyenv-virtualenv ? Which is another good reason to get pyenv too imo

Answer (score 1):

Try the commands `which pip3.12` and `which python3.12` in your
terminal to find out the path where was installed, and then add this path
to your $PATH to be the first one to be searched. This way will solve your problem.

However, a good idea is to install Python 3.12 directly from
[this page](https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/). It will update
your `.zprofile` file to contain the right path to the new version:

```sh
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Comment: Yep. Installing python from python.org is by far the simplest way.